# Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-mvc, json.net

First, It is not just duplicate. None of answers from following questions are working for me.

http://goo.gl/tS40cn
http://goo.gl/pH6v2T

I've just updated all my packages using Nuget Package Manager and I started receiving this error.

**Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)**

My Package Config has:

```
<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="7.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
```

Web.config includes this piece of code:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.5.0.0" newVersion="4.5.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Properties from Reference for `Newtonsoft.Json`

[image]

According to the answers from the similar questions, I have tried followings:

- Reinstalling package using `Update-Package –reinstall Newtonsoft.Json`
- Removing `dependentAssembly` config from `Web.config` for `Newtonsoft.Json`
- Changing `newVersion` to `6.0.0.0` and `7.0.0.0` in `dependentAssembly`. Doing so gave birth to new error.
- Also tried `Get-Project -All | Add-BindingRedirect`. It changes `newVersion` for `Newtonsoft.Json` to `4.5.0.0`. But issue remains unresolved.

Please help me fixing this.

Comment: Did you clean build folder content before building? Are you targeting the same framework version as the refernced dll?

Answer (score 15):

I know this is old,  but I just ran into the same problem.  My issue was that multiple projects in the solution used Newtonsoft.Json, but some were at different versions.  I updated all of them to the most recent (9.0.1 as I type) and the problem went away.

Anyway... if anyone is still dealing with this, make sure to update the package in EVERY project in the solution.

HTH

Comment: That was really unintuitive, but it worked. I didn't think references in different projects in the solution would affect each other. Good stuff!

Comment: @Niklas, yeah the error message is totally not helpful.  Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 2):

Add Newtonsoft reference in my MVC project solves the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

After trying much of the above (and some other posts), I uninstalled with the package manager all of the following from the project affected:

```
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi
Microsoft.AspNet.Client
Microsoft.AspNet.Core
Microsoft.AspNet.WebHost
Newtonsoft.Json
```

Then reinstalled Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi, which auto installed .Client, .Core, .WebHost, .Json.

Answer (score 1):

Run `Update-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Reinstall`

It should remove the reference to your 4.5 version, and reinstall the newer version referenced in your package.config.  It will also update the binding redirect, which should then be as follows:

```xml
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Since you said in your question that you already tried this, you might want to *first* try removing the existing reference manually.  You might also want to make sure the files aren't read-only on disk, or otherwise locked by source control.

Comment: Thanks ! I remembered, I had tried it already. But will try again and update  here very soon

Comment: Sorry for late response. After running command as suggested by you, I am still getting same error. It set binding redirect to `<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.5.0.0" newVersion="4.5.0.0" />`. I tried changing to the one which you had given `<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" />`. But it generated this error `Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)`.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error myself, and first used `Update-Package –reinstall Newtonsoft.Json -IncludePrerelease` it didn't work, then used `Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json` . it worked.

Answer (score 0):

run this command in the package manager console:

```
PM> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 6.0.1
```

Comment: Didn't worked. Got error `Install-Package : Updating 'Newtonsoft.Json 7.0.1' to 'Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.1' failed. Unable to find a version of 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client' that is compatible with 
'Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.1'`

Answer (score 0):

1. In your VS solution explorer, remove the Newtonsoft.Json reference.
2. Download the 6.0 binary files at Newtonsoft binary files [here](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/download/6.0.8/Json60r8.zip)
3. Extract the files
4. Add the Newtonsoft library manually. From Visual Studio, right click Reference and select Add Reference
5. Click Browse
6. Navigate to the extracted files under Net45 and select Newtonsoft.Json.dll
7. If it does not work try using Net40 instead by going through the whole procedure again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the following code was present in my local debug version of the solution, but not in my live server version of code. Adding the code to my server Web.config file fixed the problem.

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the config to as mentioned below:

Comment: <dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>

Answer (score 0):

check the 'Newtonsoft.Json' version in the project references. Add that version in the Web config. It will work.
For Example:
your Webconfig look like this:

```
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json"publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

If your version in References is '9.0.0.0'
change to this:

```
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json"publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```