# use stripe for payment gateway dynamically in .net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, payment

```
  @model Stripe 

    <form action="/Home/Charge" method="POST">
      <article>
        <label>Amount: $5.00</label>
      </article>
      <script src="//checkout.stripe.com/v2/checkout.js"
              class="stripe-button"
              data-key="@Stripe.Value.PublishableKey"
              data-locale="auto"
              data-description="Sample Charge"
              data-amount="500">
      </script>
    </form>


<form action="/Home/Charge2" method="POST">
  <article>
    <label>Amount: $5.00</label>
  </article>
  <script src="//checkout.stripe.com/v2/checkout.js"
          class="stripe-button"
          data-key="@Stripe.Value.PublishableKey"
          data-locale="auto"
          data-description="Sample Charge"
          data-amount="500">
  </script>
</form>


<form action="/Home/Charge3" method="POST">
  <article>
    <label>Amount: $24.00</label>
  </article>
  <script src="//checkout.stripe.com/v2/checkout.js"
          class="stripe-button"
          data-key="@Stripe.Value.PublishableKey"
          data-locale="auto"
          data-description="Sample Charge"
          data-amount="1200">
  </script>
</form>
```

I am trying to implement stripe in asp.net mvc  Here Each form submit to function accordingly , my doubt is can be show them dynamically through model and allow user to select one  payment  , and identify what subscription plan user selected in controller ?

```
public ActionResult charge(string stripeEmail, string stripeToken,int planId)
        {
            var customers = new StripeCustomerService();
            var charges = new StripeChargeService();
            var subscriptions = new StripeSubscriptionService();

            var customer = customers.Create(new StripeCustomerCreateOptions
            {
                Email = stripeEmail,
                SourceToken = stripeToken

            });

            var charge = charges.Create(new StripeChargeCreateOptions
            {
                Amount = 100,//charge in cents
                Description = customer.Description,
                Currency = "usd",
                CustomerId = customer.Id,
                ReceiptEmail = customer.Email
            });


            return View(charge);

        }


        public ActionResult charge2(string stripeEmail, string stripeToken)
        {
            var customers = new StripeCustomerService();
            var charges = new StripeChargeService();
            var subscriptions = new StripeSubscriptionService();

            var customer = customers.Create(new StripeCustomerCreateOptions
            {
                Email = stripeEmail,
                SourceToken = stripeToken

            });



            var charge = charges.Create(new StripeChargeCreateOptions
            {
                Amount = 2500,//charge in cents
                Description = customer.Description,
                Currency = "usd",
                CustomerId = customer.Id,
                ReceiptEmail = customer.Email
            });

            var subscription = subscriptions.Create(customer.Id, new StripeSubscriptionCreateOptions()
            {
                PlanId = "paln2"
            });




            return View(charge);
        }
```

This is my controller here submit for each form is added This code works fine but what is need is i want to change this hardcode and make them dynamically ,

Comment: I'm not familiar with Stripe, but presumably you could add all the prices to the page, each in their own `<div>` and hide/show the divs as appropriate? Also, for future reference, some more context/details of the problem would make this easier to answer. For a start, what do your controller and ViewModel look like?

Comment: @Akuria I am also looking for the same,
here i am getting an issue as
Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: could you help me with this one?

Comment: @Madhav  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32806744/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-newtonsoft-json-or-one-of-its-dependencies

Comment: @Madhav  Issues related to reference can be resolved , I had achieved  my task let me know if u want any help with Stripe

Comment: @Amal sebastian,
Thanks for your reply.
It the starting I had issue related with Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0 i resolved that and when debugger hits the line
             var customer = customers.Create(new StripeCustomerCreateOptions
            {
                Email = stripeEmail,
                SourceToken = stripeToken
            });
this method then i get this Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, issue.so for now i got stuck with this one.can you help with it?

Comment: @Madhav Bro what version Is your Netwonsoft.Json  ?

Comment: 6.0.1 is the version of my Netwonsoft.Json

Comment: @Madhav   Can you Upgrade it into 9.0 and check if issue is solved

Comment: actualy i did this and then i start getting issue regarding Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0 which arises in gloabal.asax.cs file
and i just tried it too,gives same issue at WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration); in gloabal.asax.cs file

Comment: can .net framework's version couse such a issue?
mine is 4.5.

Comment: @Madhav https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet/issues/551 bro please have a look it seems there is some problem with 4.5

Comment: don't know what's the issue exaclty,
I have changed the version of .netframework from the solutions property's  and still i have the same issue.
what was the version of framework on which you have accomplished this task?

Comment: Resolved the issue ny removing the line of code
 WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
from Global.asax.cs file

Comment: @Madhav Great Bro , Hope by now  you have  implemented Stripe  too

Comment: Stripe Payment Integration in Asp.net Web Forms and its 100 percent  working code and you can also download application 
https://code2night.com/Blog/MyBlog/Implement-Stripe-Payment-Gateway-In-ASPNET